# Using sharepoint search API, how to retrieve all documents within all sites within my sharepoint tenancy?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

The code snippet I have below is retrieving all documents in one document library inside one site.

I want to be able to retrieve all documents inside all document library's inside all my sites/tenancy.

```
  public getDocuments() {
    axios 
    .get("https://bpdev.sharepoint.com/sites/KIM/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList2')/items?$select=*,FileRef",
            { params:{},
              headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
            })
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({
        documents: response.data.d.results
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Any idea how to update my endpoint to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you can use search to get all document by contentTypeId

/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x0101*'&selectproperties='FileRef'

Comment: This does not seem to return the documents I have in the document librarys. Such as .csv or .txt files?